# How to protect the posting data / parameter is not modify by user and try to bypass the checking?

Tags: php, html, post, get

I am working on a shopping cart website,

I created a table to display to the user tp order like this:

```
+---------------------------------+
| My order list                   |
+----+------------+---------------+
| ID | NAME       | ACTIONS       |
| id | name       | update delete |
| id | name       | update delete |
+----+------------+---------------+
```

The problem is I identify the edit item like this:

```
mydomain.com/product_list/edit/1
```

Where `1` is the table ID of the product list

It is really dangerous as other user can delete the records of other by trying to tamper the id. How to secure this one? Even by posting, the hacker can just create a fake posting page, and post the fake id to the program.

Thanks

Comment: Possibly sessions? And making sure the users are "attached" to the ID they are trying to delete?

Comment: session is not modifiable by the user? I see

Comment: You're going to have to link the users to their tables somehow. So how do you do that now?

Comment: you mean how I get the list for the user?

Comment: when the user login, he use the email , so from the email I can get the user id , and from that id I can get the order list

Comment: Then it looks rather simple, ensure the user is logged in before even looking at deleting the table?

Comment: if I have already use session , do I still need extra checking e.g. whether the record is own by the user etc...

Comment: since the order id is just by number , e.g. order id 1 is the first record for customer A , order id 2 is for B, 3 for A etc... so if user B type in / post 3 as parmeter then he can delete the record of user A

Comment: Something like (*pseudo code*): `if(session.email == database.user.email && GET.id == database.user.table_id) { delete table; } else { user not owner, can't delete table. }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read your question and comments. And I think storing owners of tables in another table can help you (if I get you right)

You said

> since the order id is just by number , e.g. order id 1 is the first record for customer A , order id 2 is for B, 3 for A etc... so if user B type in / post 3 as parmeter then he can delete the record of user A

Before you let me alter the table, you have to check if I've permissions for this. You can check my e-mail, my password, add them to session etc. But when it comes to check query string, you can simply look if this table is one of my tables.

So if user B type in / and post 3 as parameter, you can go and check if B is one the owners of table 3. If no, don't let B do anything.